# WCF Data Services + Azure error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, azure, wcf-data-services

I've developed an ASP .NET MVC 4 application that uses Entity Framework and a service WCF Data Services.

Everything works well offline. When I deploy my application on Windows Azure Cloud Services, my website and database work perfectly, but when I try to reach my WCF service appending "/MyserviceName.svc/" at the end of the url, I get the following error:

The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'The type initializer for 'System.Data.Services.Providers.ResourceType' threw an exception.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:
at System.Data.Services.Providers.ResourceType.get_PrimitiveResourceTypeMap() at System.Data.Services.Providers.ObjectContextServiceProvider.PopulateMetadata(IDictionary`2 knownTypes, IDictionary`2 childTypes, IDictionary`2 entitySets) at System.Data.Services.Providers.BaseServiceProvider.LoadMetadata() at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateMetadataAndQueryProviders(IDataServiceMetadataProvider& metadataProviderInstance, IDataServiceQueryProvider& queryProviderInstance, BaseServiceProvider& builtInProvider, Object& dataSourceInstance) at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateProvider() at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest() at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.ProcessRequestForMessage(Stream messageBody) at SyncInvokeProcessRequestForMessage(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)

I have searched for a solution, I saw forums saying that I should add System.Spartial.dll, Odata.dll and Edm.dll on my project, but I already have these libraries into my project.

So, how could I fix that ?

Thanks in advance,
DevCrosser

Answer (score 1):

Try marking the assemblies as "Copy local" in your project before you deploy

It's possible they're not being copied to the server

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The 3 libraries that I have talked about in my question are set to copy local: true. Many others are set to false, should this be the reason of my problem ?

Comment: It's possible that you've got something else loaded into the GAC on your machine that the server is missing

Comment: So, do you think that if i set all my librairies to copyLocal: true will it work ?

Comment: It feels like overkill to do it for all the libraries, but it would rule out missing something on the server!  At least if you do that and it works you can start narrowing down the actual one that's missing (or rule it out as the cause of the problem completely)

Comment: I will try this asap and I'll tell you the result

Comment: I finally fixed it !

Instead of modifying the "copy local" property on my DLLs, I updated the version of Microsoft.Data.Services to 5.2.0.0 rather than 5.0.0.0 because System.Spartial.dll was also in 5.2.0.0

Then, I modified the "Factory" attribute in my .svc class with the new version of my dll.

    Factory="System.Data.Services.DataServiceHostFactory, Microsoft.Data.Services, Version=5.2.0.0

I re-deployed the whole project on Azure, and it worked !!